# parser sax in php with accented letters

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I have a problem with accented letters.

For example:
I have a tag that contains: "il mio prodotto é molto bello". However, the output is: "il mio prodotto "

When in xml, and there is an accented letter, the date is cut. I have a xml with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Here is my parser code:

```
<?php
class Content_Handler {
   function Content_Handler(){}
   function start_element($parser, $name, $attrs) {
       global $desc, $names, $link;
       if ($name == "PRODUCT"){
          $zupid = ($attrs["ZUPID"]);
          echo "$zupid<br>";
       }
       if ($name == "DESCRIPTION") { $desc = true;}
       if ($name == "NAME") { $names = true;}
       if ($name == "DEEPLINK") { $link = true;}
   }

   function end_element($parser, $name) {
       if ($name == "PRODUCT") {
          print "<br />";
       }
   }


   function characters($parser, $chars) {
       global $desc, $names, $link;
       if ($desc) { echo $chars."<br>"; $desc = false;} 
       if ($names) { echo $chars."<br>"; $names = false;} 
       if ($link) { echo $chars."<br>"; $link = false;} 
   }
}


$handler = new Content_Handler();
$cat_parser = xml_parser_create("UTF-8");

xml_parser_set_option($cat_parser, XML_OPTION_TARGET_ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1");
xml_set_object($cat_parser, $handler);
xml_set_element_handler($cat_parser, "start_element", "end_element");
xml_set_character_data_handler($cat_parser, "characters");


$file = "my.xml";


if ($file_stream = fopen($file, "r")) {

   while ($data = fread($file_stream, 4096)) {

       $this_chunk_parsed = xml_parse($cat_parser, $data, feof($file_stream));
       if (!$this_chunk_parsed) {
           $error_code = xml_get_error_code($cat_parser);
           $error_text = xml_error_string($error_code);
           $error_line = xml_get_current_line_number($cat_parser);

           $output_text = "Parsing problem at line $error_line: $error_text";
           die($output_text);
       }
   }
} else {

    die("Can't open XML file.");

}
xml_parser_free($cat_parser);

?>
```

Comment: What does "the date is cut" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the normal error when dealing with SAX parsing in what appears to be any language (see previous answers on java and C!).

When you are a parsing SAX events, the Characters function isn't the entire contents of the element between the start and end tag, it can be called many times, and when you are dealing with accented characters it is.

The full characters contents can only be determined by concatinating the values between a start and end tags.

so for your term '"il mio prodotto é molto bello', characters will be called probably 3 times, with 'il mio prodotto ', 'é' and ' molto bello', so you need to concatinate them, not use them as litterals.

Your 'characters' function should be more like:

```
function characters($parser, $chars) {
   global $desc, $names, $link;
   $fullchars .= $chars;
}
```

with your chars being used and reset in the end_element and start_element.

Comment: ok thanks for the answer.but how can save the fullstring for NAME in a variable?

Comment: I have no idea what NAME is and where you put the variables are just implimentation issues. If name is the name of the tag you are in, then it is presumably set in the start tag, and cleared in the end tag. If you get to the start or end tag and you have info in the chars, you know there has been some data. What you do with that data is wholly dependant on what you need to do with it.

Comment: That is a different question. Close this one (mark as answered if you are happy) and open a new question about the sql

Comment: oyyyy  thanks very much. the script run very well. but now i need to inserti this data in my sql. how can i do it?

Comment: @Woody , thanks, it help me to correct https://sourceforge.net/projects/ods-php/ which I fork, improve and push on https://gitlab.com/bcag2/ods-php